# SQLDataReader returns string with additional break characters \\\\

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I am using `SQLDataReader` in C# to query a SQL table. One of the fields in this table is a string that holds a file path, for example `"C:\\Files\\MyFiles"`.

However, `SQLDataReade`r returns this string with two additional backslashes. For example: `"C:\\\\Files\\\\MyFiles"`.

SQLDataReader appears to be detecting the escape character "\". Is there anyway I can stop it doing this?

Comment: That's what you will see in the *debugger*, is that where you are looking?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the debugger. I'm trying to compare two strings, but they don't match because of the extra "\". So I can't debug this?

Comment: The debugger displays the strings in their escaped form, so if you see \\ there is really only \ - as you expect, all is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is somehow misleading for some developers when inspecting the value in visual studio. You get a string like this:

```
C:\\\\Files\\\\MyFiles
```

But when you print it to the console you get the exact string:

```
Console.WriteLine(path); /* C:\\Files\\MyFiles */
```

**You can click the Magnifier icon** to check the exact string characters. So no worries, you're safe to go **it is just Visual Studio adding some escape characters.**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `\\\\` with `\\`.